# Sign-in with google for android not working in release apk

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-signin

I have added the Google Sign in in my application and made it work by following all the steps in the official documentation.
Everything worked fine, until I generated a signed apk for publishing. The app could not sign in , the

```
Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
```

in SignInActivity.java's `handleSignInResult()` gives the value as `false`.

I have registered the app on the developer console and provided the SHA1 key for they debug key as well as the release key. I am unable to solve this and couldn't find anything related in the documentation either.

Comment: in your google-services.json file, is the package name (android client) the same as your release apk's application Id?

Comment: Also, have you downloaded and put the `google-services.json` file in your app's module's root?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34264043/android-google-auth-sign-in-get-id-token-handlesigninresultfalse

Comment: @ElvisChweya yes, all that is done correctly, and it works in the debug apk.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Finally solved it. I added the SHA1 key for my release key (the `.jks` file) in the Google Developers Console under the project registered. 
In Android Studio, at the left side, there is an option for Build variants under the project view. There, I changed each module to `release` mode (it is in `debug` mode by default). Then created the Signed APK by usual method, and run the app. The Google Signin worked perfectly.

[image: Changing the build variants]

Comment: where to add SHA1 key in developer console?? can u gve me exact path??? and how to find SHA1 key...help..its urgent

Comment: for me..in studio its already in release mode bu still handleSignInResult:false coming..what to do??? any suggestions???

Comment: Go to your developer console https://console.developers.google.com, click on the icon to top left to open the drawer, click on API manager. Go to the Google+ aPI under Socil API. Enable it. Click on Credentials at the left in the drawer. If you see any credentials added already click on them and in the details you will see a field for adding SHA1. Otherwise click on Create Credentials > OAuth Client ID > Select Android. Fill the necessary details and save.

Comment: yes..i did that but still issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36999751/google-signin-not-working-in-release-mode-apk-android/   can you help me???

Comment: whether we have to add this key somwhere in the android code? manifest???if so where??

Comment: @SanketPimple How did you change it to release mode?

Comment: @PaulaKristin check my edit, I have added an image. Read the answer again, you'll get it.

Comment: @SanketPimple did you use Firebase?

Comment: Please Provide acurate path. Where to add new release SHA 1 Key in developer console ?? can you give me exact Path .............. how to find release SHA 1 key

Answer (score 24):

When you upload an apk to the play store then play store creates a new SHA1 key called "App signing certificate". You get that SHA1 and save in your console or firebase account (as you need).

New SHA1 will be found at Released Management->App Sigining on your play console.

or

when you build signed apk with your filename.jks it has different SHA than your debug apk, put these SHA which is generated by signed apk in Firebase nd update it and again download json from firebase and override existing json from your android studio.

> Before publishing app you should read [Google Play launch checklist](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/launch/launch-checklist)

> For complete release process you can go [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish)

Comment: Your answer is confusing because if you want to upload APK into playstore then you need use the keystore for signing. We only use that keystore file SHA1 value for firebase or any 3rd party services

Comment: after your publish your apk in playstore, it wont work for your google service until you put SHA1 generated by playstore in your firebase account.
For Firebase
Debug SHA is different 
Release SHA is different(Signed APK)
Playstore SHA is different.

Your firebase services work only after you put playstore SHA in Firebase settings.
i was experiencing this problem, when i release my app on playstore it was not working for google sign in service, to make it working you have to put SHA1 generated by playstore in firebase settings. @VinayagaSundar

Comment: thanks. i just add SHA1 from  Google Play App Signing  on firebase and update google_services.json on app. Thanks

Comment: @Guihgo Did it fix the issue?

Comment: @AmarIlindra yeap !

Comment: Thank you so much, You saved my day@AmeyaSalagre

Comment: I am unable to find new SHA on google play console as well as .jks file. please help

Comment: You will get New SHA1 at Released Management->App Sigining on your play console. @PriyaJagtap

Comment: Its only showing options for Export, encrypt, and upload your app signing private key.,Generate and register your new upload public key,Enroll in Google Play App Signing.         There is no direct way to get SHA1. @ Ameya Salagre

Answer (score -1):

Go to  `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17` [Java jdk/bin location].
Open `cmd` as administrator

Follow Steps:

```
cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17

keytool -list -v -keystore "KEY STORE PATH" -alias "KEY ALIAS"
```

Enter Password

Done!