# google signIn not working in release mode apk android

Tags: android, google-signin, release-apk

In release mode, my google sign-in is not working, but it works fine in debug mode. I got a similar question from SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35561657/sign-in-with-google-for-android-not-working-in-release-apk), but I didn't get perfect solutions.

My `handleSignInResult` is coming `false` - How can this be fixed?

Comment: Go to Google console >> Select the Project >> Select Credentials from left menu >>Select OAuth client for Android type >> You can see the SHA1 key written over there, that may be the development one >> Replace it with release SHA1 >> Save. That's it!!

Comment: In my case problem was as:

Comment: I have same problem but how to create release sha1 key? @SunitSamanta

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Make sure you follow all the steps specified in the [Guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating#prerequisites)

. If need be, create a new OAuth Client, new configuration file (the `google-services.json`) file and do everything step-by-step.

Also try adding a Web Client giving the same credentials. 
And for Android as well as Web client give both the SHA1 for debug as well as the release keystores.
In Android Studio, at extreme left you will see a tab saying "Build Variants". Select the release mode there and do everything after that.

Comment: it worked...i created new OAuth Client where i used release apk SHA1 key.

Comment: I have a doubt...if i want to edit my code like add new features i will convert it to debug mode..then what happen to my OAuth Client...which was made using release SHA1 key right???

Comment: You can add multiple SHA1 in the console. And If it worked earlier in debug mode, it should work again.

Comment: I keep coming back to this answer. I have to use the Web key instead of the Android key.

Comment: @Sanket I could not understand your second para "Also try adding a Web...". Could you please elaborate

Comment: @ShikharJaiswal I meant the Type as Web Application. But please check the steps for the newer app signing service.

Comment: Thanks, i just copy the SHA-1 from google console and i paste it in the firebase project settings and then it worked!, thanks again

Answer (score 171):

Yesterday same problem occurred to me.

Google has released a new signing service in playstore publish console in which google will signin your app with his keystore. After signing , it will give you a new SHA which you have to add in your firebase account.

[image: Enter SHA provided by Google in your firebase account]

Comment: This is perfect solution. you have to add app SHA1  and Play store also.

Comment: I just copied all SHA-1 keys to the Firebase Console from the page above, downloaded the google-services.json, compiled and works fine.

Comment: @HarshitG pls check my issue at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55235295/google-signin-working-in-release-apk-but-not-on-play-store

Comment: Which SH1 needs to be added in firebase App signing or Upload certificate? Is it needed to download the google-service.json file, build release app and upload updated app to playstore again?

Comment: @Nbn Add both SHA1

Comment: Ughh you just saved me so much trouble; thank you... So there's a separate SHA for adding an app and one for playstore? Interesting. Thank you

Comment: I wish I could vote this one up like a hundred times!!! Thank you!
I now understand ... there is an upload certificate and google manages the signing certificate for the store. Gradle's signingReport task of course doesn't give you the latter.

Comment: do we need to upload again after adding play store sha1 on firebase?

Comment: @Oush I will send you my address... :-P

Comment: @HarshitG have u experienced invalid google token issue after all this steps?

Comment: It is strange how google has not made easy access to App Signing page. I had to google for the specific link and could not find normally from the play-store developer console. Also, i don't think their doc regarding google sign in mentions the above step. Very misleading i would have thought from google's side.

Comment: For anyone looking in 2021+, it's now on Play console -> setup ->  App integrity

Answer (score 64):

**When you upload app on play store**

**After signing , it will give you a new SHA which you have to add in your firebase account.**

[image]
[image]
**Its Working HAPPY Coding Cheers**

Add new SHA1 in https://console.firebase.google.com

**Create Release SHA1 using Command Line**

keytool -list -v -keystore "E:\Jsk_file\healthNickel" -alias healthNickel

keytool -list -v -keystore "**E:\Jsk_file\YOUR_JKS_FILE_NAME**" -alias **YOUR_JKS_ALIAS_NAME**

Enter keystore Password :- **YOUR_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD**

[image]

Answer (score 56):

I had same problem, i did read some posts and was able to get work done by following below steps

Step 1)  Please go to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?

Step 2)  Click on create credentials ->select OAuth client ID ->select application type as Android

Step 3)  then generate Signing-certificate fingerprint by writing below command in command prompt **before that you should have keystore and its path**

```
     keytool -exportcert -keystore "D:\PlayStore_keystore\myproject.jks" -list -v
```

Step 4)  after click on enter you will be asked for

```
     Enter keystore password : 
     Enter password which you have used for creating keystore
```

Step 5)  then it will give details regarding keystore like **SHA1,SHA256,MD5** etc.

Step 6)  Enter SHA1 as fingerprint and give packagename which is in manifest file

step 7) **Click create you will get new OAuth client ID**

step 8)  now you have got client id you will need to get google-services.json file.

step 9)  please goto https://console.firebase.google.com

step 10) if you already have project with that packagename ->go to overview ->click on menu icon where packagne name is written

step 11) select settings goto-> project Settings-> add Android app (in the bottom) -> there will be option called Add fingerprint

step 12) in step 5 you have got SHA1 paste that in certificate fingerprint and save it

step 13) now download new google-services.json file (as it conatins new client id ,certificate_hash etc)

step 14) paste that google-services.json file in app folder in your android project.

step 15) You are good to go...

Comment: what i did was go to the dashboard console and activated app signing with google, then uploaded my certificate and it signed it but generated a new set of has code values that i then used in the firebase console. This worked for me. so your answer provided me a hint since i understood what was wrong

Comment: @xwaxes glad it helped

Answer (score 10):

Go to Play store and Search for "App Integrity"

[image]

Google play store app integrity

Then
Copy the SHA Keys and Add into the Firebase or Google Cloud signing keys.

and then you are good to go.

Answer (score 7):

Because you are asking about release version of Android so I assume you already have signed your application with keystore.

So in order to obtain the **SHA1** of your release app.

- Go to your `/bin` in JDK directory.
- And run the following command in your cmd.

```
  keytool -list -v -keystore "key store path" -alias "key alias"
```

This command will give you all the required details of your release version.
Copy the **SHA1** string and add it to your firebase console.

You are good to go.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211919/errorkeytool-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-p

If keytool is not recognized

Comment: thanks a ton man, I had my key.jks file I ran this command and got the sha1 and added to firebase console and that worked like charm

Comment: also it is important to remember that when we release a new version to the playstore the new hash has to be added to the firebase console

Comment: Thank you, worked!
wasn't able to run my release build variant locally before releasing to make sure everything is working, but your answer helped!

Answer (score 4):

Ok I struggled with this and finally I found the solution here it is:

First of all there are three SHA1 keys

1. Debug SHA1 key
2. Release SHA1 key
3. SHA1 key when you google play sign your app

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34933381/5705721) you can get debug and release keys and for third key check HarshitG's answer.
There is App signing certificate, this is that key.

Gather those three keys and add them in [firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com) under **SHA certificate fingerprints**

Then Download the `google-services.json` file and add it in your `YOUR_PROJECT_NAME/project/app/` [you'll see it if you change the view to `Project` from `Android`]

Rebuild, generate release apk and enjoy :)

Comment: That helped, thank you! Good thing is we need to add keys in Firebase console only, we don't need to add them to Google Cloud Console. In the Cloud Console, they are propagated automatically by and from Firebase.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you are using any google api you must add your release hash key on  the app you generated in  google developer console if you have added hash key for debug.

Comment: u need to create pass your keystore path instead of debug keystore 
this is tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cWDM0lZl_C0

Comment: i created SHA1 key for my release apk using this https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth then added to developer console..where i already iave a SHA1 key..whether i should delete that?? or just add this one too???

Comment: u can add new it does'nt matter

Comment: when you hit api using debug apk then that specif hash key wil be used and vice versa for released or signed  apk

Comment: yeah i did everything like that..but still handleSignInResult  is coming false :(

Comment: hmmmmm i tried my best .well I think you should share your code as well. May be some one could help you more

Comment: :( shoo... what to do :( now

Answer (score 1):

For a **Release** *(aka, Signed)* APK: If you are only deploying to Firebase, you need to add the **SHA1** for the same keystore file you used to sign the app.

After successfully adding the **SHA1** into the Firebase Project console ,  get the latest `google-services.json` and update your project's module local copy.

I didn't see any docs on this so far (seems it's something you have to dig for); found it to be tricky stuff.  Lot's of answers on SO.  Found the Firebase deployment solt. thanks to:

1. Answer in this thread to update SHA1 on Google Play, it gave me the idea maybe I need to fix something with SHA1: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44307293/2162226
2. How to get the SHA1 for a signed APK: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34933381/2162226

Answer (score 1):

1. in the terminal go to the project folder->android-> paste this command and hit enter ./gradlew signingReport . this will generate set of keys for you .
2. Then copy the SHA1 and SHA256 keys under release release label.
3. add them in to  your Firebase settings keys section.
4. Download the googleServices.json and replace your existing googleServices.json with the new one and build the apk again.

hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Best And fastest way to fix login social media by flutter application using firebase after upload the app in google play to solve problem
go to google play console than setup > app integrity > from App signing key certificate copy sha1& sha256 and past in firebase account in android app add new sha1 and sha256 .
for facebook error login also copy sha1 from App signing key certificate in google play console go to this website : http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php
past in hex string and click covert than copy output base 64 and past inside app setting in facebook development

that's all

Comment: I would give you one million upvotes, but stack overflow won't let me. You saved me a mini heart attack on an app in production :D
For Flutter, this is your quickest fix if signing in worked in debug mode, but not release mode.

Answer (score 1):

***CAUTION***

If exist you put more than one identifier for the same 'signingReport' (copy SHA1 and SHA256 from the same report object) this isn't work, keep this im mind.

**This works for me:**

- Remove all SHA1 in firebase
- Run `./gradlew signingReport` in android folder and get SHA1 from debug mode.
- Run this commmand with your data:
  `keytool -list -v -keystore your_absolute_path_to_keystore -alias your_alias_from_keystore`

> (After that you will be promped to digit the password of key and it
> wil generate your SHA1 + SHA256 and other infos.)

- Copy only SHA1 and paste it in firebase.
- Download `google-services.json` again and move it to your `android/app`

Answer (score 0):

If you have two or more firebase projects or the google cloud project, there may be a duplicate SHA1. If such conditions have been explained in this link.

https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6401008?authuser=0

Answer (score 0):

### Before mindlessly running commands n stuff lets get some concepts straight!!

---

Your app needs to get signed by a **signing certificate** / **keystore** (that .jks file) to create a release build. Release builds are created in either **Debug mode** or **Release mode** (We'll learn about this futher on)

There are 3 types of these keystore files that you will come across:-

1. **Debug keystore** generated by using `./gradlew signingReport`
2. **Upload keystore** generated by [following these instructions](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#create-an-upload-keystore)
3. **Deployment keystore**/**Play Signing keystore** which is automatically generated by Play Console when you first try to upload a app bundle there. (You can find it at `Setup > App integrity > App signing`). This keystore stays with Google. You do not have access to its `.jks` file. So its safe and wont get lost.

---

Now, I would say, if you wish to get your app on Play Store, DO NOT generate **Debug keystore**. Generate and ALWAYS use your **Upload keystore** only.

***Why is this important?***

- **Debug keystore** are just able to sign your apps in **Debug mode** (not **Release mode**).

  > Even if you try to use `flutter build appbundle` with `--release` flag, you are gonna get a `app-release.aab` which is signed in **Debug mode**! You can never publish an app signed in **Debug mode** in Play Store.
- **Upload keystore** can sign your app in **Release mode** which can be published on Play Store.
- Therefore, if you intend to publish your app in future, generate upload keystore by [following these instructions](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#create-an-upload-keystore) and make changes to you gradle files accordingly. Do not generate that debug keystore cuz you wont need it.

This explanation should make you understand that why some answers are wrong which recommend to get a **Debug keystore**

---

### Now the proper answer to the above question.

Certain Google Play services (such as Google Sign-in and App Invites) require you to provide the `SHA-1` of your **signing certificate**

So if you are signing you app with **upload keystore**, add the `SHA-1` fingerprint of your **upload keystore** in `Firebase Console > Settings Icon > Project settings > Add fingerprint`[image: add SHA-1 fingerprints]

- You can get the `SHA-1` of **Upload keystore** using `keytool -v -list -keystore /path/to/upload-keystore.jks`
- Also, you can get the `SHA-1` of **Upload keystore** and **Deployment keystore** on Play Console at `Setup > App integrity > App signing`

---

### Which `SHA-1` should I add? There are two `SHA-1` at Play Console.

You have to add both `SHA-1` fingerprints to firebase.

**Why?**

- For **publish reviews** you always have to submit your app signed with your **Upload keystore**. Play Console will accept your app update submission signed with that same **Upload keystore** only (So keep the **Upload keystore** safe). That's why, to make that **Upload keystore** signed App work properly you need to add **SHA-1** of **Upload keystore** in Firebase.
- After your **publish review** is **Accepted**, your app will be signed again using the **Deployment keystore** by Play Console (automatic), then it will be published on Play Store. So that's why  to make that **Deployment keystore** signed App work properly you need to add **SHA-1** of **Deployment keystore** in Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

**This answer for people who using Visual Studio Xamarin Forms.**

After I upload my app on Google Play I thought it will work, but it didn't, I did every Sha1 ,APIs but still not working, after weeks of trying I just change one option in Visual Studio, Then Release version start working very well,
then I Archive .abb file and sign it with release keystore upload it to Google Play and finally working.

This is the method, right click on your

**YourApp.Android -> Properties -> Android Options -> Code shrinker and select None**

Here is image for my options

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did face the similar kind of problem while creating an app ***using expo***.

If you are able to sign in while you are running the project in expo but not in APK, then it's definitely the ***problem with the certificates***. Make sure you have pasted all the ***sha1/sha256*** in the Firebase console (as I used Firebase, I am writing this with respect to it).

***If app is published***

If you have published the app for ***internal purpose*** (as I had published it for internal purpose) in google play console, then paste the certificates provided in the play console. Google play console -> setup -> internal app sharing -> copy sha1/sha256 from the internal test certificates.

If you have published the app publicly then you can refer the above answers that will definitely help you.