# Android : Google signin is not working in release mode

Tags: android, google-signin, release-mode

Google Sign in is working fine in debug mode but not working in release mode apk, can anyone help me here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are **two** types of keys. `Debug` and `release` key.

In development mode you have to use `Debug` key.

And In Release mode you have to use `release` key.

Comment: how will i get release key? Where to find it?

Comment: @Reoxey check this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup).

Comment: dude i tried everything...
created SHA1 with jks keystore and used in firebase console then
generated signed apk with release build variant 
enabled google sign in in authentication in firebase...
still google sign in is not working
what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You don't provide a solution. Thats not a good answer dude

Comment: @Reoxey  i had same issue had solved it here is [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36999751/google-signin-not-working-in-release-mode-apk-android/42921691#42921691)