# google signin not working with production apk on playstore.(release apk on playstore)

Tags: android, authentication, release, google-signin

Actually Google sign-in is working in debug mode but when i upload the apk on playstore,it is not working.

I made a new google project in google console. There i enable the google+ signin api. After that same project was open in firebase where it ask for sha1 key which i entered. everything is working fine in debug mode but release is creating problem in google signin.

I am uploading the pic of my google console with firebase

Please help

[image]

Comment: sha key for your `google-services.json` and `.jks` file should be same

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue but resolved it quite nicely, same with Phone Auth if you think of adding one.

Solution workers as of **23 June 2021**:

1. Go to your google play console and select your app.
2. Go to Release->Setup->App Integrity->App Signing Key Certificate.
3. Find SHA-1 certificate and copy it. The same goes with SHA-256 certificate.
4. Go to your firebase console and select your app.
5. Go to project settings and add the copied SHA-1 certificate and SHA-256 certificate.
   You should be able to log in with Google or Phone again. No need to re-upload apk/aab app to play store.

Comment: This works for me as of Dec 2021. It might take some time for login to start working after updating SHA-1/SHA-256. In my case it took around 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same key.store file for generating "signed APK" you have used for getting the sha1 key.

Answer (score 0):

You should generate SHA1 for release apk also and you have to use that SHA1 to add new fingerprint in firebase and then download the google-services.json file then it will work.

I had given detail answer where all steps are described from sign in to developer account to generate SHA1 for release,to get google-services.json file

[google signIn not working in release mode apk android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36999751/google-signin-not-working-in-release-mode-apk-android/42921691#42921691)

it will you guide through all steps.