# Release mode Google signIn not working

Tags: android

In release mode, my Google sign-in is not working. But it works fine in debug mode.
I have created release **SHA1** and updated on `https://console.firebase.google.com/project` and added **Google-services.json** in my App but getting `handleSignInResult:false`

For reference I follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36999751/google-signin-not-working-in-release-mode-apk-android) URL

Anyone can suggest what I need to do for release mode?

Comment: Can you share your app.gradle here?

Comment: can you update your log?

Answer (score 2):

I have follow below steps and now its working

Google has released a new signing service in playstore publish console in which google will signin your app with his keystore. After signing , it will give you a new SHA which you have to add in your firebase account.

Go to **play store -> Release Management->App Signing ->App signing certificate** 
copy SHA-1 and add in your firebase account.