# Google signin works on origin APK but not work on derived APK even if I added correct SHA-1 to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-signin, google-play-services

I build the APK in release mode and it worked perfectly, however after uploading to Play Store and test the derived APK it doesn't work anymore.

I added correct SHA-1 to firebase config and even updated the `google-services.json` and use the correct `web client ID`.

How I can solve this issue without effect the current production running app?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360250/firebase-ui-authentication-with-google-fails-with-message-code10-message10/51360406) out.

Comment: @AlexMamo Thanks but still not work

Comment: Finally, I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44307293/2576485

Comment: Good to hear that ;)