# PlatformException (PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500: , null))

Tags: dart, flutter, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

**The line where is going to crash:**

```
GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
```

**What have I tried:**

1. I've generated my SH1 key with this command `keytool -list -v \
   -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore`
2. Adding SH1 encryption into console.firebase.google.com
3. Re-downloading the google-service.json
4. Copying the `debug.keystore` from `.android` to `MyProject/android`
5. Run in debug and release
6. Adding into `android/build.gradle` those lines:

   - **classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'**
   - **classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'**
7. Adding into `android/app/build.gradle` this lines:

   - **implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'** under **dependencies**
   - **apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'** on the end of the file.
8. Creating a file named `release-signing.properties` under my project folder with those lines in it.

   - storeFile=debug.keystore
   - keyAlias=androiddebugkey
   - storePassword=android
   - keyPassword=android

Also, I've searched in **ALL StackOverflow** question that I could found for this question, and none of them was useful for me.

**My pubspec.yaml:**

```
firebase_core: ^0.4.0+1
firebase_analytics: ^3.0.1

cloud_firestore: ^0.11.0+2

firebase_auth: ^0.11.1
google_sign_in: ^4.0.1+3

rxdart: ^0.22.0
```

**Auth class:**

```
class AuthService {
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final Firestore _db = Firestore.instance;

  Observable<FirebaseUser> user;
  Observable<Map<String, dynamic>> profile;
  PublishSubject loading = PublishSubject();

  AuthService() {
    user = Observable(_auth.onAuthStateChanged);
    profile = user.switchMap((FirebaseUser user) {
      if (user != null) {
        return _db
            .collection('user')
            .document(user.uid)
            .snapshots()
            .map((snap) => snap.data);
      } else {
        return Observable.just({});
      }
    });
  }

  Future<FirebaseUser> googleSignIn() async {
    loading.add(true);
    GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
    // FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithGoogle(
        // accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken, idToken: googleAuth.idToken);
    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );
    FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    updateUserData(user);
    print("Sign in" + user.displayName);

    loading.add(false);

    return user;
  }
}
```

**Main class:**

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  AuthService authService = AuthService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blueGrey,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              MaterialButton(
                child: Text("Log in with Google"),
                color: Colors.blueGrey,
                textColor: Colors.deepOrange,
                onPressed: () => authService.googleSignIn(),
              ),
              MaterialButton(
                child: Text("LogOut"),
                color: Colors.redAccent,
                textColor: Colors.purple,
                onPressed: () => authService.signOut(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now if any of you could point me in the right direction I would be very grateful.

Here are some stackoverflow links that I've tried already:

1. [Google sign in doesn't work after release of flutter app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53263246/google-sign-in-doesnt-work-after-release-of-flutter-app)
2. [Flutter and google_sign_in plugin: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54557479/flutter-and-google-sign-in-plugin-platformexceptionsign-in-failed-com-google)
3. [Google Sign In error 12500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632035/google-sign-in-error-12500)

I didn't have luck with any of them, please let me know what do you think and how can I fix it.

Comment: When exactly do you encounter this error?

Comment: After I'm pressing the "Log in with Google" button I will open a pop-up where I need to select my google account. I will receive this error right after I will press on my google account.

Comment: I've added on the question the line where is going to crash.

Comment: Have you checked the logcat for a more detailed error message? Since it's a platform exception, it's failing in the platform side, so you'll sometimes find error messages in the android or iOS logs that you won't find in flutter

Answer (score 58):

The OP, @Mircea, specifically mentioned error 12500. This is how I overcame that error:

I have spent the last few days running into the same problem. I refactored my code dozens of times, added break points, reset the SHA-1, SHA-256 and did just about every other 'code' based solution I could find. I was constantly running into the error:

`E/flutter (11935): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500: , null)`

I was losing my mind so I decided to start with fresh eyes and move slowly through solutions one more time. I noticed an obscure post nestled deep in a thread that mentioned something about having a support email. It was not until I added a said **support email** that things "magically" started working. I've attached a screenshot below of the Firebase settings for my project.

[image]

Comment: It's not work with me

Comment: Yes, for 12500 error code, this is working... Thanks.

Comment: Google sign-in is working with my physical devices perfectly, but with the emulator, it shows exception 12500. what I am missing?

Comment: nope not true. already have the email address.

Comment: the support email is configured in two different places, first: in the app upon configuration, second: on enabled google login (this second one was in my case the error 12500)

Answer (score 20):

In my case, I have not enabled Google Sign In method.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

You need to complete "**Oauth consent screen**"

I went to this page (https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials)
Do not forget to select your project on the list (top left). Then go on "Oauth consent screen"

I filled the application logo and the application homepage link and aplication privacy policy link (with the project.firebaseapp.com) and saved.

[image]

Now it's working, I can login.

This must be explained in the documentation. People are going to be crazy and to don't try flutter with this kind of lack of documentation.

Comment: I added a logo like you suggested and it miraculously worked. Bit ridiculous but at least it's sorted now!

Comment: Oh, Lord! This was a life saver. I was breaking my head with SHA 1 and google-services.json

Comment: Doesn't seem to fix it for me. Furthermore, once I add an Icon it seems that I need to verify this with google, wich can take up to 6 weeks. I have literally tried everything on Stackoverflow but nothing seems to work...

Answer (score 7):

In my case, the problem was due to incompatible emulator. The emulator didn't had playstore.

I created a new AVD which has playstore in it. And then it worked!

[Reference to create new emulator with Playstore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65325614/9420335)

Also, verify that you have added the SHA1 key on firebase console.

Comment: Dude I searched evrything... and its just the Playstore....

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue, I resolved it by adding the debug / release SHA1 and SHA256 certificate fingerprint using Keytool

Release

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias <your-key-name> -keystore <path-to-production-keystore>
```

Debug

```
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

More details here: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth

Answer (score 3):

Change your emulator to another one that supports Google Play Store

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

Go to the API & Servcies page of your google account and make sure to select the project of your interest in the top left corner as shown below

[image]

Make sure you have the support email ID entered in the above

And all the below fields must have a value

[image]

Try logging in now, it will work!

Answer (score 1):

I also tried almost all answer that I can search from internet.So I decide to tried ios side then it still give me error "403 restricted client".Then I determine it's server side issue .Finally I found that Forgot to set support e-mail address in Google Developers Console > API and service > certificate > user consent screen [link](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/consent) and this option also in your Firebase project setting .After set up everything should work.Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I ran exatly into the same issue, what solved the issue for me was to add a SHA-256 fingerprint additionally to the SHA-1

as mentioned here -> [Flutter and google_sign_in plugin: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54557479/flutter-and-google-sign-in-plugin-platformexceptionsign-in-failed-com-google)

Hope that works for you too!

Answer (score 1):

After following all the steps mentioned in the documentation, even I was facing the same issue. One thing worked for me is adding the support email in the setting page of firebase console

Answer (score 1):

**POSSIBLE CASE 2023**

I had to face this problem too, during testing everything was working fine, but when I changed my project (actually build.gradle was the problem) to release mode the sign in process stopped to work as it was used to.

I tried to fill all the fields on *Oauth consent screen* (https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials), but nothing changed.

I also tried to check my SHA on Firebase, but both SHA-1 and SHA-256 were there.

As last resource I wanted to check my current SHA so in app/android folder I runned: `./gradlew signinReport` and I found out that the SHA were changed.

So I uploaded them on Firebase and now everything is working fine.

In the end, check the SHA twice.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the **Google Authentication** provider was set with a **support email** and I was facing the same problem. So, I deleted the previous porvider and re-enabled a new Google Authentication provider and replaced old `google-service.json` file with newly downloaded file in `<root>/android/app/` folder. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue was using visual studio when I changed to android studio it worked. I guess because I am signed into firebase with android studio i wander if i can do the same with VS oh well hopefully this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to this already huge list of ideas.  After trying all of the things listed here I was still getting the error.

I had to add myself as a test user under the OAuth Consent Screen.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I forgot to enable To add users manually, enable Email/Password as a sign-in method
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKRLD.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Check Application ID:-**

**Package Name** on Google api console and **Application Id** in your app must be same, in my case it was different,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to set up two things:

1. Go to Google Cloud console, select your app and in consent screen fill out the information required.
2. I was using an emulator without Play Store. After I set up an emulator with Play Store installed, it worked.