# Google Sign in return PlatformException(sign_in_failed, d.g.a.c.e.o.b: 12500: , null, null) in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-signin

This message happens in some user's phone. They reporting to us that they can't login and google keep returning that error. They have custom domain gmail account like "abc@school.com"

i searched everywhere the error message still got nothing. did you ever receive this message?

this my flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.4, on macOS 12.4 21F79 darwin-arm, locale en-ID)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.4.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.69.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

this my library version `google_sign_in: ^5.4.0`. Note: I have added `SHA1`, `SHA256` and `google-services.json` in the project

Comment: its already answered here :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56188338/platformexception-platformexceptionsign-in-failed-com-google-android-gms-comm

Comment: its different. look at my error "d.g.a.c.e.o.b" whats that mean? i didn't find it anywhere so i open this question. its happen at some phone only not eveyone. and it random.