# Some Google Accounts don't work in Google Sign In

Tags: flutter, google-oauth, google-signin

I've created an app that uses Sign In With Google. I have configured everything and got verified correctly. Everything worked fine, but today I've found out that some Google accounts don't work. Sign in requests from these accounts return 12500 codes. I've noticed that these are school accounts, but some normal accounts also don't work.

The app uses Flutter and `google_sign_in` package. Also, I'm not using Firebase for authentication, just Google Cloud project.

The exact error I'm getting is
`E/flutter (24695): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500: , null, null)`

I've tried to add OAuth scopes in the GoogleSignIn initializator like `GoogleSignIn(scopes: ["email", "profile"])` and added these scopes in the OAuth consent screen. But it still don't work

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632035/google-sign-in-error-12500 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56188338/platformexception-platformexceptionsign-in-failed-com-google-android-gms-comm ?

Comment: I have no solid idea, but maybe something is off with custom domain accounts? Many school/enterprises use their own domain for Google e-mail, like instead `@gmail.com` they can have `@mybusiness.com` or `@university.asdf.edu` etc