# Google Sign-in not working although OAuth Constent is verified

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication, oauth, google-signin

**Why????**

It's very annoying. How can it be so difficult?
I've fulfilled all requirements, and finally got the verification. But it is still not working. Why????

Edit: How can I find error messages for release apk?

[image]

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I don't where to look for error messages for release apk. it can be additional question to this post.

Comment: so it works in debug mode?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It's working for debug.

Comment: you can connect real device and run it in release mode

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53263246/google-sign-in-doesnt-work-after-release-of-flutter-app please check this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, found the solution!

I've added SHA1 under the

***Google Play Console > App Signing > App Signing Certificate***

to

***Google Cloud Platform > Credentials > API Keys > Android key (auto created by Firebase)***

and to

***Firebase Console > Project Settings***

Posts that helped me:

[Google sign in doesn't work after release of flutter app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53263246/google-sign-in-doesnt-work-after-release-of-flutter-app)

[google signIn not working in release mode apk android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36999751/google-signin-not-working-in-release-mode-apk-android)