# Flutter application does not go beyond authentication while using the Internal testing URL from Google Play

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-play, google-play-internal-testing

am trying to take my Android Flutter app to Google Play and it is now in review, meanwhile, i have internal testing going on for the uploaded package via an invite link from the Google play dev console.
Flutter application works fine when installed via Android studio, goes past the authentication page and loads BUT when the application is installed via the invite link it does not go beyond the authentication page and in fact, the firebase app authentication tab does not even show any authentication being registered.
As a result, the app is just stuck on the authentication page, with no errors etc, as if not registering the auth provided.

It is a simple flutter application using firebase authentication which only supports Google auth.
Invite link: [https://play.google.com/apps/internaltest/4699220448797061928](http://%20https://play.google.com/apps/internaltest/4699220448797061928)
The application is in the review so they have given it a temporary name: 'Pivotal Tower'

Please advice.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that these need to be done to get it going.
As described here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53263246/google-sign-in-doesnt-work-after-release-of-flutter-app/65840488#65840488][1]

I have to register your Play Store app signing key with API providers (in this case Firebase).

1. In your Google Play Console, visit Setup > App signing
2. Copy SHA-1 certificate fingerprint Copy SHA-1 from Google Play App signing key certificate
3. In your Firebase Console, visit Settings > Project settings
4. Click Add fingerprint
5. Paste copied SHA-1 certificate fingerprint into Certificate fingerprint text field
6. Click Save

Comment: For developers not using firebase, Go to your apps in Google Play Store Console > Setup >  App integrity  , then copy the SHA-1 in the App signing key certificate section, then paste SHA-1 to the oauth2 - SHA-1 certificate fingerprint- for Client ID for Android

Comment: Saved me "days" of extra work. Tanks!