# Flutter Firebase GoogleSignIn doesn't work in release

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, authentication, google-signin

I am developing flutter application with firebase, which has Google Sign In feature. The problem is my android app does not work with error: `PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)`, despite my iOS app is doing great.

I followed some answers of this [Google sign in doesn't work after release of flutter app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53263246/google-sign-in-doesnt-work-after-release-of-flutter-app) and that instruction https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating#prerequisites.

Which are:

- Copy SHA-1 certificate fingerprint in Play Store and paste it in `Firebase Console > Project Settings`
- Set up `build.gradle`
- Configure Google API console.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [google signIn not working in release mode apk android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36999751/google-signin-not-working-in-release-mode-apk-android)

Answer (score 3):

Actually SHA1 keys are different for debug and release apks

Add sha1 key of released version in firebase console your problem will be solved for sure

If your apk is published in playstore get the sha1 key from google play console and paste it in firebase