# Google Sign In error Status{statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null} from same play store app not from same signed apk

Tags: android, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

I think this is a bug in android, android studio or google.
I am able to login to google through the signed apk. But If I upload the same apk on play store it says me `Status{statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null}`.

I want to know how can it be possible that I am not able to login from the app downloaded from the Play Store and I am able to login when I use the same apk from my PC which I have uploaded to play store.

This should not be DEVELOPER_ERROR this should be ANDROID_ERROR, GOOGLE_ERROR or HOW_TO_IRRITATE_DEVELOPER_BY_ANDROID.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this ANDROID_ERROR which they say DEVELOPER_ERROR.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Status{statusCode=DEVELOPER\_ERROR, resolution=null}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37273145/error-statusstatuscode-developer-error-resolution-null)

Comment: @AjeetChoudhary, please read the question carefully before saying it duplicate. I am able to sign in with signed apk but not from the play store same apk. And the question that you referenced is not same.

Comment: Then change the question heading according to your problem, your problem may be because of SHA-1 key, it need to regenerate for release apk, check these. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35561657/sign-in-with-google-for-android-not-working-in-release-apk,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36045652/google-sign-in-signed-apk-not-working

Comment: Ok, thanks for your suggestions and references. I have already generated release keys. one more thing I would like to ask you. I had previous project with same package, then due to some other errors I had to delete it. Do deleting takes time form more than a day? Because I am using the same package name.

Comment: I don't face the problem with the signed apk. Signed apk is working fine. But face the problem when I install the same app from play store.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I got this issue few days ago and i solved this by following the google guideliness

1.make sure the google JSON file your adding in App folder must be from the developer account.
2.Update all keys in the firebase account, release and debug key.

3.(important step): there is tab called "App signing" in Release management section in your google play console.

Google has released a new signing service in playstore publish console in which google will signin your app with his keystore. After signing , it will give you a new SHA1 key which you have to add in your firebase account.

after adding that SHA1 key to your Firebase account. try login, it works fine

Comment: Thank you! After three hours of googling, your third step saved me! This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: Great! Its works great. I was suck on this issue long days its resolved now with Google App signing SHA1 key, If i use the JKS file SHA1 the Google login failed always.

Answer (score 0):

I was using an existing project to create google sign in. I logged the issue on android as well, but didn't get response till now [Issue Repoted Here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63944059).

So, I created a new Project with new packagename in Android Studio and copied paste all my required files (Resources and Java files only) from previous project. Created a new project for google sign in and followed the procedure by [google](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start)

Now I was able to sign in properly.

I think (Not Sure) Android Saved some data from previous project in and it was not cleaned even after cleaning and rebuilding the project. So at last I had to create a new project.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem ... i searched a lot tell i found the solution here.

> "Google has released a new signing service in playstore publish console in which google will signin your app with his keystore. After signing , it will give you a new SHA1 key which you have to add in your firebase account.
>   after adding that SHA1 key to your Firebase account. try login, it works fine"

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/4943560/sanjay-km