# Google Sign In produces a statusCode of "Developer_Error"

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-signin, sha1

I've searched and tried almost everything given on Google Developers website, Stack Overflow and other helpful blog posts. But nothing has worked for me.

My app was successfully signing-into the Google account but when I made some basic changes in the app (not related to Google API at all) and uploaded the updated APK on playstore, **Google Sign-In** hasn't worked after that.

When I run the app from Android Studio (using `debug` build-variant and `release` build-variant), sign-in works like a charm. Then I generate the **signed-apk** and upload it on Play Store. And when I install app from Play Store, it doesn't sign-in and gives **statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR**

I've created the project on Google Cloud Console, created OAuth 2.0 client ID for Android inside that project and added `SHA1` (generated for **release**) inside that client ID. Then I downloaded `google-services.json` file and placed it inside **app** folder of my project.

I don't seem to miss anything. But sign-in still doesn't work. Please let me know what's the problem.

P.S.: Firebase is also integrated into my Android Project.

Here is the set-up code for `GoogleApiClient` inside `onCreate()`

```
googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(MainActivity.this, this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, signInOptions).build();
googleApiClient.connect();
```

This is the method invoked when Sign-In button is clicked.

```
public void signIN() {
        Intent intent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE);
}
```

This is the code from onActivityResult()

```
if (requestCode == REQ_CODE) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if(result.isSuccess()){
                GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                //Do something
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to Sign in. Try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            Log.d("GoogleResult", result.getStatus().toString());
}
```

Comment: have you generated sha1 for released apk.?

Comment: Yes @SardarKhan as I mentioned in the question statement, I've generated SHA1 for release apk.

Answer (score 6):

Nothing wrong with your code.

Apparently, Google has introduced something called "App signing" into the Google Play Developer Console.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45273726/1139514) (which worked for me!), you have to go to Release management > App signing in the Google Developer Console.

There you see "App signing certificate" and "Upload certificate". Both SHA-1s plus your debug SHA-1 should be added to the Firebase Console.

Comment: I also had this same issue and had to find out the hard way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Marco7757. But as I mentioned in my question statement, I've added `SHA1` to Google Developer Console. And secondly `SHA1` can only be added at one place (Google Developer Console or Firebase Console) otherwise it shows the error of **duplication of SHA1**.

Comment: There are *three* SHA-1s. Debug, release and the Google app-signing SHA-1. Have you added all three?

Comment: Thank you. This is the right solution for this issue. It has sense, when you are developing in Android Studio, you need to generate the SHA1 and put it on Firebase Project Settings. Then when you publish your app, you need to add the SHA1 certificates generates from Google Play Console. After this you don't need to do anything else and the login works instantly in your app installed in your phone.

Answer (score 0):

I had also faced the same issue once. It was because I was using some other OAuth2.0 client.

Here is what you should do :

Use the oauth2.0 id, you find at this key's value

Open your google-services.json

```
project-info > client > oauth_client[1] > client_info
```

Make sure you have added the SHA1 Fingerprint of your release and debug keys, in firebase general settings and using the updated .json file.

.

Comment: I'm using updated `.json` file. And I've also added `SHA1` fingerprint for both (debug & release) in Google Developer Console for the same project that is linked with my Firebase Project.