# Why is my Google OAuth2 Sign in working, disregarding of my apps signing keystore

Tags: xamarin.android, google-oauth, xamarin.auth

In our app we are using the Google Drive REST API. To authenticate, we're using Xamarin.Auth with the following configuration

```
var authenticator = new OAuth2Authenticator(<our client ID>,
                                            null,
                                            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
                                            "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth",
                                            <our redirect url>,
                                            "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
                                            null,
                                            true);
```

The login is presented using

```
var loginPresenter = new OAuthLoginPresenter();
loginPresenter.Login(authenticator);
```

(this is not the actual code, since the authorization is encapsulated in a class and the authenticator and the presenter are injected, but basically this is what we're doing).

This will open a login form in a browser and allow the user to login, resulting in the form calling back our app with a OAuth2 token. Everything works like a charm.

Our client ID has been created using the hash of our debug keystore. According to the docs and other questions (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36999751/google-signin-not-working-in-release-mode-apk-android) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35561657/sign-in-with-google-for-android-not-working-in-release-apk)), this should cease to work in release configurations when the app is signed with a different keystore. Anyway, having signed the app with our internal testing AdHoc keystore, the login form still works without any issues. Actually I do not see how it should not. After all, all we do is opening a website in a system browser control, hence I do not understand how the website is supposed to get our apps hash.

Since the linked questions lack details, I can't see how they are different to our situation, but I somehow assumed Google OAuth to do some black magic to ensure that the hash matches. Is there any reason that this works for us? Can we expect it to keep working after it's been uploaded to Google Play or is there any risk that it stops working?