# Google Sign in is not working for release variant but working flawlessly for debug variant

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

My google sign in is working perfectly for debug variant. But when I tried to build the release variant it stops working...I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35561657/sign-in-with-google-for-android-not-working-in-release-apk) answer but in my case I haven't uploaded to my app to play store yet. So how can I get my new sha1 keys in this case?

Comment: Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360250/firebase-ui-authentication-with-google-fails-with-message-code10-message10/51360406) will help.

Comment: that answer includes the google play store keys as well...but i don't have those since i haven't uploaded my app on play store yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360250/firebase-ui-authentication-with-google-fails-with-message-code10-message10/51360406) [@Alex Mamao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5246885/alex-mamo) pointed out.

You can create the SHA1 keys in your project. On the right handside of Android Studio > Gradle > app > Tasks > android > signing Report

You have to go to your google play android developer console. ([play.google.com/console](https://play.google.com/console)). Even without uploading something you should find general > Setup > API access. Turn it on and it will open the google cloud console and create a project automatically. ([console.cloud.google.com](https://console.cloud.google.com)) There you can create the API tokens for your android app underneath APIs & services. Without releasing this allows only a provided list of testers to login with google auth. Afterwards anyone can opt-in.

Comment: I used the method @Alex Mamo pointed to it worked! Apperently you don't need the google play store keys if you haven't released your app on play store