# Google authentication not working for bundled apk of react native app

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, google-authentication

I posted this question earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69769672/google-sign-in-is-not-working-for-release-variant-but-working-flawlessly-for-deb) and according to the answer provided I added the SHA keys of the release variant in firestore and even downloaded the google-services.json and placed it in my app folder. Now google auth works perfectly for release variant built using npx react-native run-android --variant=release but then when I built the bundle of that app, used bundletool to convert .aab file into apks and installed this apk, google authentication doesn't work. Do I need to add any other SHA keys? What am I doing wrong here?